# external library linked with cmake can not be found at runtime

Tags: c++, cmake, fortran

I have linked an external c++-library to an existing cmake project using the following cmake commands:

```
SET (some_src 
  .
  .(sourcefiles here)
  .
  .
  .
  .
)

ADD_LIBRARY(some_proj SHARED ${some_src})

# Adding precompiled NURBS lib
SET(nurbs_libs ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/nurbs/libs)

ADD_LIBRARY( nurbs_C SHARED IMPORTED )
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES( nurbs_C PROPERTIES 
                                  IMPORTED_LOCATION ${nurbs_libs}/surface.so.1.0 
                                  LINKER_LANGUAGE "CXX")

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES( some_proj nurbs_C )        

SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_PATH ${nurbs_libs})

INSTALL(TARGETS some_proj DESTINATION lib)
install(FILES ${nurbs_libs}/surface.so.1.0 DESTINATION lib)
```

When trying to run a program that uses the library I keep getting the error

```
reels: error while loading shared libraries: 
surface.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I tried playing with LD_LIBRARY_PATH and RPATH but to no avail. I suspect I did something wrong with the cmake file. How can I handle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Because you have binary file compiled, there is probably no problem with your CMakeLists.txt. Use [ldd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ldd_%28Unix%29) to find out which libraries you are missing. Also check that you have surface.so.1 present on disk (probably it would be link directing to surface.so.1.0)